# empty value inserted when parameter is false

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to insert FALSE value in the database, without any luck - it inserts an empty string. The column is varchar. If I insert TRUE value, it inserts 1.

I'm using mysql, PDO and php.

I'm also using a DB class which does nothing more with the query than preparing and executing it using PDO prepared statements.

The query in mind is a very basic one:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO api_logs_values (value) VALUES (?)';
```

and then:

```
$this->_db->query($sql, array(FALSE));
```

any ideas what is happening?

**EDIT:**

Added table structure:

```
api_logs_values | CREATE TABLE `api_logs_values` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`log_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `log_id` (`log_id`,`name`)
ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**EDIT2:**

I've found a bug report concerning this here https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33876, but there doesn't seem to be a proper, nice solution to this. Except maybe setting the PDO_PARAM_BOOL attribute.

**EDIT3:**

I've found out that the DB class that I am using does not bind the params separately, but does execute($param), and looking here http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php, it treats all params as PDO::PARAM_STR, which is not correct.

Comment: You are trying to insert `FALSE` into a `VARCHAR` column? Or `'FALSE'` ?

Comment: Try to insert exact string value, e.g 'FALSE' or '0'.

Comment: I'm inserting a boolean FALSE, not a string 'FALSE'. I want it to work the same as it would if I would do a query INSERT INTO something (column) VALUES (FALSE) manually through the console. In this case it would insert 0, not an empty string like it does through the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've found the solution. The problem was in the way binding of the values was done in the database class I was using. It was doing something like this:

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($param);
```

But stating from http://lt.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php:
It takes a parameter:

> **input_parameters**  An array of values with as many elements as there are bound parameters in the SQL statement being executed.  All
>   values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR.

What the database class had to do was call [bindValue()](http://lt.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) first with an appropriate data_type parameter (PDO constant). This comment sums it up nicely: http://lt.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php#104939

Answer (score 3):

If you want to insert the string "false", then `$this->_db->query($sql, array("FALSE"));`

For datatype `varchar`, php value of false is considered as empty string.

If you want `TRUE` to be `1`, and `FALSE` to be `0`, set the datatype of the column to `tinyint`.

Comment: No, I want to insert the bool value FALSE and see 0 in the database.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL will insert values that evaluate to false into columns.  Depending on the datatype the actual value will differ.  For character-based datatypes, an empty string will be inserted.  For numerical types it will insert 0.  You should use an appropriate data type.  (FYI, while MySQL recognises the keyword BOOL for datatype definitions, the column will actually be created as TINYINT.  In this case it will store 1 for true and 0 for false)

If you want to literally store the string "false" then you need to use a string literal instead of boolean false.

Comment: Why does it insert 0 if executed from the console, and an empty string if using prepared statements?

Comment: Into the same column? Don't know.  If you mean the same value into different columns then what gets stored is dependant on the datatype of the column.

Comment: No, I'm talking about the same column, the same query. Just one of them queried from PHP with PDO prepared statements like so INSERT INTO something (column) VALUES (?) and another like so INSERT INTO something (column) VALUES (FALSE). The first one inserts an empty string even if I pass FALSE as a param to the query() function, and the second one inserts 0.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL implements booleans as follows:

BOOL, BOOLEAN
These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered false. Nonzero values are considered true.

(from: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

Comment: I know that. I'd like it to insert 0 into the column, and not an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a "strict mode" issue of mysql.  I know the command line client gives gracefully to help "convert" the string 'false' into 0 for datatype TINYINT(1).  It will produce a warning, but it'll go in.  This is not the case for JDBC does not.  PDO may be acting funky..

See JDBC bug report: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=24526

See MySQL SQLMode Strict: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables

Comment: Your comment "PDO may be acting funky" led me to an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should really try to match the datatypes.
One simple if is sufficient to achieve this.
The code will look like this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO api_logs_values (value) VALUES (?)';
$value = false;
$value = ($value === false? '0':'1');
$this->_db->query($sql, array($value));
```